# Trying to work with classes in Objective-C but failing to do so

Tags: objective-c, class

I am brand new to Objective-C and am trying to get around how classes work, I am able to create the class and then methods inside it, then `#import` the class into the `AppDelegate.m` file. However, the issue arises when I reference the method inside the class, e.g. `[class1 something]`

Originally, I had the following in my `class1`'s header and main files:

header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface class1 : NSObject

- (void)something;

@end
```

main:

```
#import "class1.h"

@implementation class1
- (void)something
{
    NSLog(@"Hello, World");
}
@end
```

But in doing so, I was faced with the following error when I called the method `something` from `AppDelegate.m`: `No known class method for selector 'something'`

Then I tried changing the `- (void)` to `+ (void)` in both header and main class files because I read somewhere than `+` would make the method a `class method` and `-` would make the method an `instance method`. I tried that and then ran the code and got the following error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried searching for a solution to the error but found none.
Is there anything I am doing wrong? Is my understanding of Objective-C classes wrong? Please help!

Comment: Show how you tried to use the `class1` class in your app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, when you are referencing the class from the class you created, and the app delegate,  you are correct in all the things that you have done.

Make sure that you do the following:

- make sure that your method is -(void) something
- make sure you #import it
- initialize the class in the delegate
- call the method

like so

```
 //in app delegate
 #import "className.h"

 className *classN = [[className alloc] init];
 [classN something];
```

This will initialize the class as an object, call the method from that class, and make it call the NSlog.

Then make sure you take it from memory

```
 [classN release];
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now tried this but when I try to call `[class1 release]` I get: `arc forbids explicit message send of release` and `release is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode`

Comment: and without `[class1 release]` I get: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: ahah! I found the mistake thanks to your error, I was referencing the main file because I saw that the main file imported the head and if I referenced the head, how would the function in main execute? Now it built successfully.

Comment: The only issue now that I'm facing is I am not able to release the memory the way you have told me to, should it be in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{…}` ? Thanks

Comment: yea, I had mistaken the code I wrote. you have to make sure that you create an object pointer to find the address of the class :) but glad I could help!

Comment: ah well I'm still not able to release but you solved my main issue. Also is there any better resource which I can access compared to apple's support documentation? I feel it's written for more advanced programmers. Thanks!

Comment: well if you search on google for objc documentation you might find easier to understand stuff on that, but it will most likely be out of date information, and can sometimes be quite misleading, so I'd just stick to apple's stuff. For the memory releasing, it isn't really necessary unless you're creating a memory hog application. For your simple thing, you won't need it, but it's just a good practice so that when you're using complex information, you can learn how to manage the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with naming conventions. Classes should have a capital letter as the first letter of the name. So change `class1` to `Class1`.

Next, `- (void)something` is an instance method, so you need to create an instance of `Class1` to call the method on. You should keep it as an instance method, that is probably what you want, not a class method.

```
Class1 *class1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
[class1 something];
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said and I am still getting the following error: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` is this error even to do with classes?

Comment: Did you add your class to your apps target?

Comment: Your answer was correct as I had missed the allocation but I accepted the other answer because it made me realize I had to import the header not the body, I up voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the class to access non static methods.

```
class1 *firstObject = [[class1 alloc] init];

[firstObject something];
```